# ios: UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have dynamically added some buttons on the scrollView as

```
`int separotorWidth=2;


  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(noOfTabs*100+(separotorWidth*(noOfTabs-1)),0)];
    UIView* tabHolder=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, noOfTabs*100+(separotorWidth*(noOfTabs-1)), scrollView.frame.size.height)];

   int x=0;
    for (int i=0; i<noOfTabs; i++) {
        UIButton* tab= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [tab setTag:i];
        x=(x+100)+separotorWidth;
        [tab setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tabTitles objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        tab.titleLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        tab.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        tab.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
        [tab setBackgroundColor:[ViewUtil blueColor]];

        [tab addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [tabHolder addSubview:tab];
        if (i==5) { //say 5th tab
            selectedBtn=tab;
        }
    }
    [scrollView addSubview:tabHolder];`
```

I want to programmatically scroll the scrollview to make sure 5th button is visible. I tried the following method but didnt work `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:selectedBtn.bounds animated:YES];`

Kindly provide me the best way to do that.

Edit:Answer

```
 if ((selectedBtn.frame.origin.x+selectedBtn.frame.size.width)>(scrollView.frame.origin.x+scrollView.frame.size.width)) {

        CGPoint btnRightTopCorner= selectedBtn.frame.origin;
        CGPoint btnleftTopCorner=btnRightTopCorner;
        btnleftTopCorner.x=btnleftTopCorner.x+selectedBtn.frame.size.width;
        CGPoint contentRightTopConer=btnleftTopCorner;
        contentRightTopConer.x=contentRightTopConer.x-scrollView.frame.size.width;

        scrollView.contentOffset = contentRightTopConer;

    }
```

Comment: the scrollview frame is (0,0,350,50).

Comment: Edit:Answer will work like scrollRectToVisible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move the scrollview programmatically Instead of

`[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:selectedBtn.bounds animated:YES];`

try this one

`scrollView.contentOffset = selectedBtn.frame.origin;`

Comment: Thanks @Vishnuvardhan, If I give scrollView.contentOffset = selectedBtn.frame.origin , the selected view comes to first position ie (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

make sure you set the following in your scrollView.

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Pradumna Patil, If I give scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO, manual scrolling is not working..